# How to achieve the equal block-chain token distribution (Airdrop)?

Tags: distributions

Let us assume that there are multiple accounts, and that one person can have more than one account. The problem is that I do not know how many people there are and how many accounts each individual has. The only thing I know is how many accounts there are, and how much money is stored on each. What I would like to do is to distribute the money to those accounts but to make sure that each individual gets an equal sum of money. The best approach I can think of is to give each account a random amount of money, however, I think that there could be a better approach.

Which approach would work better than distributing it at random, to achieve an equal distribution of wealth ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't give any account anything. Then, everybody gets the same number of tokens: zero.

This is the most that can be done when you have no way to tell which account belongs to whom.

Comment: Null is not an option.